# .net core after publish event run powershell script

Tags: powershell, .net-core, visual-studio-2019

How to add post-publish event to an mvc .net core project that
after publish execute a powershell script in a project directory?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=208121. 
-->
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.0</TargetFramework>
    <ApplicationIcon />
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <StartupObject />
    <UserSecretsId>f572b776-d17e-4de4-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxx</UserSecretsId>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <Target Name="CustomActionsAfterPublish" AfterTargets="AfterPublish">
    <Message Text="First occurrence" Importance="high" />
  </Target>
</Project>
```

So this messgae part works, but I would like to put if possible `./pb.ps1` and do I need to set execution policy?

Comment: So much information missing... remember we have no clue of your issue and would like to reproduce it.

Comment: My issue is how to attach random powershell script to a post-build event. What else of information do you need?

Comment: Why are you directly editing the project XML?

Comment: Because I saw an example on SO for writing a message in console, so I assumed that this is a way also for powershell call

Comment: This can be done directly from the project properties post-bulid via the VS GUI.

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/r857dT6.png You mean like this? what I need to enter in order to call powershell script? for example `.\test.ps1` or `run .\test.ps1`?

Comment: No, you have to use a CMD command by calling powershell.exe

Comment: Oh I see..can you post an answer?

Comment: This should help you out:https://davidfrette.wordpress.com/2011/01/20/creating-powershell-pre-build-and-post-build-events-for-visual-studio-projects/